# Facing difficulties to grab dynamic value from api generated multiple checkbox value with v-model in vue 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-component

I am very beginner to vue js.

this is my code. I just getting the questions form api and for loop them as a question. inside the question i also get the available questions and so i print them with for loop too.

```html
<div v-for="(item, index) in data.slice(12, 15)" :key="index" class="mb-80">
  <label
    for="formGroupExampleInput2"
    class="form-label text-bold checkbox-custom-head"
    >{{ item?.id }}. {{ item?.question }}</label
  >
  <div
    v-for="(option, key) in item?.option"
    :key="key"
    class="checkbox-custom-div"
  >
    <input
      :id="`checkbox-${option?.id}`"
      v-model="formData.option_id"
      :value="option?.id"
      class="checkbox-custom"
      type="checkbox"
      @change="handleChange(item?.id)"
    />
    <label :for="`checkbox-${option?.id}`" class="checkbox-custom-label">{{
      option?.option
    }}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my script code to grab the checkbox selected value

```
const formData = reactive({
  option_id: [],
  question_id: '',
  cookie_id: '',
  user_id: '',
})
```

but after pressing the checkbox i get this output

```
[
   0: 1,
   1: 2,
   3: 3
  .......
]
```

but i need to get the output as

```
[
   12: [ 1,2,3]
   13: [9,10,11]
  ..............
]
```

thanks in advance

Comment: "i want this output" doesn't explain how something should work.  please give a description for what your code is trying to do.  What does `12: [1,2,3]` mean? You want your array to start at index 12? What should fill indices 0-11?  what is `data`? is there a reason you're using `slice` and is it related to your desired output?  what is the `@change` method doing?  you've not explained anything about the actual code.

Comment: sorry for this messy explanation. Let me explain what this code actually doing.

first I have bunch of questions in my data props . so i slice them up into some short sections for the desire view. I have questions in first for loop (item) and I have options in second for loop (option) according to question. On change method is used for only to see the output here of v-model. so when i clicking a checkbox i am getting a normal array with option id. but i need them with item id as index and then how may option i selected. 12: [1,2,3] here 12 is item  id and rest are option id